# writing time equal number of line in file text

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to write time in every line in front of Text by check number of line in text file. Because I want to convert this text file to .srt file by this link.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111024/how-to-convert-a-txt-subtitle-file-to-srt-format

Every one line is 1 second.(start first line at 00:00:00:) My file has many line (500-1000 line up)
from

```
.......Text......... (first line)
.......Text......... (second line)
.......Text......... (third line)
    .
    .
    .
.......Text......... (60 line)
.......Text......... (61 line)
    .
    .
.................... (3600 line)
```

to this

```
00:00:01:.......Text......... (first line)
00:00:02:.......Text......... (second line)
00:00:03:.......Text......... (third line)
    .
    .
    .
00:01:00:.......Text......... (60 line)
00:01:01:.......Text......... (61 line)
    .
    .
01:00:00:.................... (3600 line)
```

Now I can check number of line and write text in front of text every line.
But error when use code check numberline and open file write text.
I don't know how to write for loop and compare number of line. I'm noob for this.

```
def numberline(fname):
    with open(fname) as f:
           for i, l in enumerate(f):
                  pass
    return i + 1
numberline("/home/pi/gtest.txt")) 

dataFile = open("/home/pi/gtest.txt", "w")
    for line in range(numberline("/home/pi/gtest.txt")):
dataFile.write("00:00:%02d:\n" % line)
    dataFile.close()
```

Please help me. Thankyou
This my project wait for this part because this is last part in python.
Normally I use Rpi with linux command but not understand in python.

Comment: You can get the number of lines in a file using,
`num_lines = sum(1 for line in open('FILE_PATH'))`

Comment: How to use for when second run to 59 and 60 is 00 again and minute is 01

Comment: You can keep the current time from `datetime.now()` in a variable and then print the time difference you get every second passes using `datetime.now()` again and formatting it using `strftime()` into the required format.

Comment: I want to start at 00:00:00: When I use datetime.now() time is current time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `enumerate()` function to get the line number and the line from a file when iterating, and `divmod()` to divide-and-remainder a number. Here we do it twice, first to get from just seconds (the line number) to minutes and seconds, then from minutes to hours and minutes.

Then, we use regular `%` interpolation with the `%02d` specifier to turn the hours/minutes/seconds variables into zero-padded two-character-length strings, and glue them together with colons to the original line.

For added meta points, this script annotates itself by default. :)

To write the output to another file, it's easiest to just do it using the shell:

```sh
$ python this-script.py > annotated.txt
```

This is Python 3, by the way; the `print()` statement would look different on Python 2.

*EDIT:* Added argument parsing as per discussion in comments. The script now allows

```
$ python this-script.py inputfile.txt > annotated.txt
```

---

```py
import argparse

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('input', default=__file__)
args = ap.parse_args()

with open(args.input, 'r') as f:
    for line_number, line in enumerate(f):
        minutes, seconds = divmod(line_number, 60)
        hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
        print('%02d:%02d:%02d:%s' % (hours, minutes, seconds, line), end='')
```

Comment: It's error at last line.  (end='')
                     print('%02d:%02d:%02d:%s' % (hours, minutes, seconds, line), end='')
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Compilation failed.

Comment: As said, this is Python 3. Use your Python 3 interpreter, e.g. `python3`.

Comment: Ok I can run it. Can I ask one more question. How to use this form when I execute from terminal. $ python3 this-script.py myfilename.txt > annotated.txt I use in shell script but files is change name every time not just gtest.txt.

Comment: @Kong Let me augment it a little.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import datetime

str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=666))
result = ''
countTime = 0
for line in open('/home/pi/gtest.txt'):
    result = result + (str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=countTime)) + ":"  + line) + '\n'
    countTime = countTime+1
print (result)
```

You can then just write the result to the file:

```
with open('/home/pi/gtest.txt', 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write(result)
```

Comment: How I use this form. ./append.py  gtest.txt  > test.txt

Comment: you can do this in the end:
`with open('/home/pi/gtest.txt', 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write(result)`